# Replacing values greater 1 in a large pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to replace all numbers greater than 1 with 1 while keeping the original 1s and 0s untouched in the entire dataframe with the minimal effort. Any support is appreciated!!

My dataframe looks something like this but contains way more columns and rows.

```
Report No   Apple   Orange   Lemon   Grape   Pear
One           5       0        2       1      1
Two           1       1        0       3      2
Three         0       0        2       1      3
Four          1       1        3       0      0
Five          4       0        0       1      1
Six           1       3        1       2      0
```

Desired Output:

```
Report No   Apple   Orange   Lemon   Grape   Pear
One           1       0        1       1      1
Two           1       1        0       1      1
Three         0       0        1       1      1
Four          1       1        1       0      0
Five          1       0        0       1      1
Six           1       1        1       1      0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this.

### Using boolean mask

```
df.set_index('Report No',inplace=True)
df[df > 1] = 1
df.reset_index()

Report No   Apple   Orange   Lemon   Grape   Pear
One           1       0        1       1      1
Two           1       1        0       1      1
Three         0       0        1       1      1
Four          1       1        1       0      0
Five          1       0        0       1      1
Six           1       1        1       1      0
```

Or use this if you have some *non numeric* columns. No need to use `set_index` and `reset_index`. This is equivalent to [`df.select_dtypes('number')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html)

```
val = df._get_numeric_data()
val[val > 1] = 1
df
Report No   Apple   Orange   Lemon   Grape   Pear
One           1       0        1       1      1
Two           1       1        0       1      1
Three         0       0        1       1      1
Four          1       1        1       0      0
Five          1       0        0       1      1
Six           1       1        1       1      0
```

### [`df.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html)

```
df.set_index('Report No',inplace=True)
df.mask(df>1,1).reset_index()
Report No   Apple   Orange   Lemon   Grape   Pear
One           1       0        1       1      1
Two           1       1        0       1      1
Three         0       0        1       1      1
Four          1       1        1       0      0
Five          1       0        0       1      1
Six           1       1        1       1      0
```

### [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
df[df.columns[1:]] = df.iloc[:,1:].where(df.iloc[:,1:] >1 ,1)
```

### [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

This can be helpful when dealing with multiple conditions. If you want to convert values less than 0 to 0 and values greater than 1 to 1.

```
df.set_index('Report No', inplace=True)
condlist = [df >= 1, df <= 0] #you can have more conditions and add choices accordingly.
choice = [1, 0] #len(condlist) should be equal to len(choice).
df.loc[:] = np.select(condlist, choice)
```

Like Jan mentioned use [`df.clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html)

---

**Not recommended** but you can try this for fun. Using [`df.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html).

```
df.set_index('Report No',inplace=True)
df.astype('bool').astype('int')
```

*NOTE:* This will only convert *falsy* values to `False` and *truthy* values to `True` i.e. this will convert `0` to `False` and anything other than `0` is `True` even negative numbers.

```
s = pd.Series([1,-1,0])
s.astype('bool')
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool

s.astype('bool').astype('int')
0    1
1    1
2    0
dtype: int32
```

### [`np.sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html)

When values present are between `[0, n]` i.e no negative values.

```
df.loc[:] = np.sign(df)
```

Comment: Why is the last method not recommended?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html):

```
new_df = df.clip(0, 1)
```

EDIT: To exclude the first column by name (this will edit the DataFrame in-place)

```
mask = df.columns != "Report No"
df.loc[:, mask] = df.loc[:, mask].clip(0, 1)
```

Comment: new_df = df.clip(0, 1) didn't work well because 'Report No' column is string. Is there any method that we can isolate the 'Report No' and perform a pandas.DataFrame.clip?

Comment: See the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and easiest way is to go through all the keys of the datframe and change them using the where function of numpy (library which has to be imported). Then we simply pass as an attribute to that function the condition and the values for when the condition is satisfied or not. In your example it would look like this:

```
for x in df.keys()[1:]:
   df[x] = np.where(df[x] > 1, 1, df[x])
```

Note that in the loop I have quited the first key because its values are not integer