# how to modify all columns values based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 1000 date columns. the value of every cell is all numeric. I'd like to replace any cell's value larger than 10 to be 10 for all the columns.

for individual columns, I know how to do it, but not sure how to do it for all the columns

```
SPM_data.loc[SPM_data > 10] = 10
```

I am also thinking to do this way, and got an error

```
def max_value(cell):
    if cell>10:
        return 10

SPM_data=SPM_data.apply(max_value)
SPM_data

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I end up doing this way using for loop, not efficient but it can be done. any one has other better faster approach? thanks

```
def max_value(cell):
    if cell>10:
        return 10
    else:
        return cell

for col in SPM_data:
    SPM_data.loc[:,col]=SPM_data.loc[:,col].apply(lambda cell : max_value(cell))
```

Comment: What object is SPM_data?

Comment: it is a dataframe with 1000 columns

Comment: it is a pandas dataframe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing values greater 1 in a large pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61996932/replacing-values-greater-1-in-a-large-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for:

```
mask = SPM_data > 10
SPM_data[mask] = 10
```

Here, `mask` is a boolean mask over the entire dataframe and the second line broadcasts 10 to all `True`s.

Answer (score 0):

## Any cell value greater than 10 discards 10 for all its columns.

```
import pandas as pd
  
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Sam', 'Andrea', 'Alex', 'Robin', 'Kia', 'Jhon'],
                   'Age':[14, 25, 7, 8, 21, 45]})
 
print(df)
print('')
df.loc[df['Age'] > 10, 'Age'] = 10
print(df)
```

Comment: thanks cryptosu. I knew this approach, which is not what I meant, sorry for confusion.  What I meant is check for all the columns instead of just individual column.